# How to config timezone with Vagrant, Puppet and Hiera?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet, hiera

I'm using [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com) for my testing environments, which is based on Vagrant/Puppet+Hiera.

In the config.yml (Hiera config file) I would like to add section for my timezone

and with command  <kbd>vagrant provision</kbd> setup it properly.

It's that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add your timezone to whatever key you want in your hiera file, let's call it `timezone`. The value for which and the puppet code you'd need to set that timezone depends on the system you're firing up, but I'll assume RedHat flavor of unix.

I recommend setting that to any valid value you'd see under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. As an example your key may look like:

`timezone: 'US/Pacific'`

Then you'd use the `file` puppet type to symlink `/etc/localtime` to the full path of the timezone:

```
$tz = hiera('timezone')
file {'/etc/localtime': ensure => link, target => "/usr/share/zoneinfo/${tz}"}
```

Comment: I'm actually on [puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64](https://vagrantcloud.com/puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64). Should I update and /etc/timezone content too?

Answer (score 6):

You can install [Time Zone plugin for Vagrant](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-timezone) (`vagrant plugin install vagrant-timezone`) and configure *Vagrantfile* in the following way:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-timezone")
    config.timezone.value = "UTC"
  end
  # ... other stuff
end
```

Instead of `UTC` you can also use `:host` to synchronize timezone with the host.