# How to Correct Timezone

Tags: php, vagrant

I set my vagrant server's timezone to Asia/Tokyo. However, though I made change in php.ini and restarted httpd, it doesn't return the correct time. The time is 9 hours late from correct time. When I change the time zone Europe/Berin, I see the time changes but it also doesn't return correct time.

Here is my php code

```
echo('<pre>');
var_dump(date("Y/m/d G:i:s"));
echo('</pre>');
exit;
```

php.ini

```
date.timezone = Asia/Tokyo
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Well what does it show for each of Europe/Berlin and Asia/Tokyo? Is it possible that the system clock is just wrong?

Comment: see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Comment: @Jon Skeet When I set the timezone to Asia/Tokyo, it returned "2015/11/03 7:23:25" but the time in Tokyo at that time was 2015/11/03 16:23. When I set the timezone to Europe/Berlin, it returned "2015/11/02 23:34:10" but the time in Berlin at that time was 2015/11/03 08:34. It seems it is possible my system clock is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config timezone with Vagrant, Puppet and Hiera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105108/how-to-config-timezone-with-vagrant-puppet-and-hiera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way out. The reason the code above didn't work was that my system clock was wrong, so I executed the command bellow.

First, I installed ntp.

```
sudo yum -y install ntp
```

Second, I got the correct time from ntp.

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.nict.jp
```

That's it. Thanks for suggestions!

A helpful link:
http://pyoonn.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/06/121925

Answer (score 1):

Also restart your apache once you have changed in `php.ini`.

Just try this once,

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
    var_dump(date("Y/m/d G:i:s"));
    exit;
```

Demo [Here](https://eval.in/461948)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code but the returned time was not correct. It returns "2015/11/03 7:17:18", but now Tokyo's time is   2015/11/03 16:17.

Comment: Yes I did. Your code works fine. The time seems correct. However, when I execute your code in my environment, it doesn't return correct value.

Comment: what is the mistake you are getting in your machine??

Answer (score 0):

first Set it like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
```

Make a simple function:

```
function getCurrentDateTime(){
    return date("Y:m:d H:i:s");
}
```

And call it anywhere you need:

```
$time = getCurrentDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Time Zone plugin for Vagrant](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-timezone) by:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-timezone
```

and use set `config.timezone.value` in your *Vagrantfile*.